# Remote not working on new iMac

Tags: itunes, imac, remote-control

My shiny new late 2012 iMac arrived, but I can't seem to get it to respond to my Apple Remote.

I tried searching the System Preferences to see if out if the box it was paired to another remote, but I can't find that option any more.

I love using my Remote with iTunes and Plex. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new iMac does not have an infrared receiver. You will not be able to use your Apple Remote. For controlling iTunes, I recommend [Remote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remote/id284417350) from the App Store. For Plex, I recommend [Plex](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/plex/id383457673) from the App Store.

Whereas in the past Apple promoted the idea of using your Mac as a media hub (hence the inclusion of the Front Row app), I think Apple is now promoting the idea of using an Apple TV instead. It seems like every new hardware refresh is having the infrared capabilities removed.